# Did the italian parliament deny what mayor of Alzano Lombardo say about people in his city not being hospitalized because hospitals are full?

Tags: medical-science, italy

There is a report from Italy in many webpage which says

> "There are many elderly people at home with breathing difficulties.
>   They are not hospitalized because the hospitals are full" said the
>   mayor of Alzano Lombardo Carmelo Bertocchi

[Coronavirus update](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/)

Some italians in forums say this is an hoax and one said the italian parliament denied this. Is there any record of the italian parliament denying this statement by Alzano Lombardo mayor?

Comment: Who is saying this is a hoax? Can you include a link or screenshot of the statement, and explain why it's a notable claim?

Comment: @LShaver No, I can't , because it's in private groups. It's a notable claim because several ones are saying it and driving the public opinion in a direction.